# insert json to html table

Tags: php, html, json

Just looking for some help in finding what's causing my code to not execute. I've made a database and php to pass it's data into json format. The issue is I want to pass this into a table, but nothing happens.
My php code

```
<?php

//$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM exampletable");
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "assignment6";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', $password, $dbname) or die("Unable to connect");

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM exampletable";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

//create an array
$emparray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($emparray);
$conn->close();

?>
```

Script

```
<script>
var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, myObj, x, txt = "";
obj = { "Name":"customers" };
dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    txt += "<table><tr><th>Name</th></tr>"
    for (x in myObj) {
        txt += "<tr><td>" + myObj[x].Name + "</td></tr>";
    }
    txt += "</table>"        
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
};
//https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_php_db
xmlhttp.open("POST", "customer.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-
urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("x=" + dbParam);
}
</script>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the Developer Tools (F12 in Chrome) and setting breakpoints in your JavaScript to see what data you're getting back from your Ajax call (and to make sure it's executing at all)?

Comment: The error seems to lie in `myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText); `.  `this.responseText` seems to be the JSON and intire script code+HTML. Still unsure how to fix this.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using jQuery?  It makes Ajax a lot easier.  Otherwise if you make a JS Fiddle with your current code I might be able to help more.  Since I don't have access to your schema it would be difficult without a sample.